# How do I secure a HTML login form?

Tags: html, forms, security, web

I need to add a basic level of security onto a web login form to allow a user to proceed onto another page. Is there a way of doing this easily? I do not need a large amount of security, although encryption would be preferential, I'm not sure if PHP would be the best way to go. So far all I have is this (with styling removed):

```
<html>
<form name="input" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 User ID: <input type="text" name="user" tabindex="1"><br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2">
 <input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3">
</form>
</html>
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a basic SSL (Secure Socket Layer).  That will encrypt the transmission of the data.  All hosting providers offer SSL as an option for shared hosting plans.  For dedicated hosting you will need to install your own cert which you can get from godaddy, geotrust, verisign, or a number of other vendors.

It doesn't matter what server side language (php, asp, rails, etc) you use.  you're site/login will not truly be secured until you implement some level SSL.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is used by most major companies. I know Facebook uses it. It all depends on how well you can code it. Also hashing passwords in the database would always be the way to go. Also SSL or TLS is needed. SSL is more used which means its probably more reliable.

[Password salting & hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)